# Guide on building .inf files?

Tags: windows, installation

Can anyone point me to a guide for creating inf files?  In particular, I'm looking for a parameter reference for the SetupInfObjectInstallAction command that you use to set up an uninstall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some time ago (like 5 years ago) I remember I solved a problem with INF by checking the Microsoft DDK documentation, so from my personal experience I would suggest to start there.

I found a couple of old bookmarks that I think won't really help you for your particular case, but they are OK if you're still trying to understand INF files (these also come in top if you search in Google):

[Creating Windows INF Files](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/archive/w2inf.mspx)

[INF Files for Bears of Little Brain](http://www.wd-3.com/archive/InfFiles.htm)